# PHP curl_setopt() is not returning the exact result_array from SOLR

Tags: php, arrays, curl, php-curl

I am using PHP **cURL**  for retrieving the search result array from **Solr**.

```
 - cURL Version : 7.47.1
```

the below code is searching for total shops in a particular city.
please see my code..

```
    $ch1 = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8983/solr/Search/select?q=searchshop%3A*&fq=" . $encode_fq_city . "&wt=php&fl=LoginInfoId");
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $shop = curl_exec($ch1);
    curl_close($ch1);

    print_r($shop);
```

I do  `print_r` the `$shop_arr` array and the result is showing only the 10 records. the actual Solr `result_array` contains 14 records.

also attaching the result array..

```
            [response] => Array
                (
                    [numFound] => 14
                    [start] => 0
                    [docs] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [LoginInfoId] => 246
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [LoginInfoId] => 230
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [LoginInfoId] => 236
                                )

                            [3] => Array
                                (
                                    [LoginInfoId] => 217
                                )

                            [4] => Array
                                (
                                    [LoginInfoId] => 241
                                )

                            [5] => Array
                                (
                                    [LoginInfoId] => 219
                                )

                            [6] => Array
                                (
                                    [LoginInfoId] => 239
                                )

                            [7] => Array
                                (
                                    [LoginInfoId] => 231
                                )

                            [8] => Array
                                (
                                    [LoginInfoId] => 232
                                )

                            [9] => Array
                                (
                                    [LoginInfoId] => 257
                                )

                        )

                )
```

The result is showing  `[numfound]=14` but only results 10 records.

is there any mistake in my scenario to get the `result_array` from Solr to PHP ?

is it a cURL Bug?

Comment: Is it possible your query is limiting the number of returns? Is there a LIMIT in the db query?

Comment: yes. it's possible. but i didn't set anything! also the `numFound` is 14 and showing only 10.

Comment: Well, the cURL side of things looks fine, my assumption is it's broken on the End Point. I'm not sure why you're using that Eval either - why not just `$shoparr = $shop;` ??

Comment: also tried with  the  `$shop`. Still same result.

Comment: Same result, just cleaner. There is no need for the Eval statement there. You should also consider using json encode/decode if possible(won't be the problem here). Can you post the code from your End Point?

Comment: you can find it in my above code. I am fetching data from solr with `CURLOPT_URL`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128999/discussion-between-telen-stanley-and-kaylined).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr by default returns 10 documents:

> **rows**
>
> This parameter is used to paginate results from a query. It specify the maximum number of documents from the complete result set to return to the client for every request. You can consider it as the maximum number of result appear in the page.
>
> The default value is "10", which is used if the parameter is not specified. If you want to tell Solr to return all possible results from the query without an upper bound, specify rows to be 10000000 or some other ridiculously large value that is higher than the possible number of rows that are expected.

So add to your query a rows parameter, for example `rows=100`:

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8983/solr/Search/select?q=searchshop%3A*&fq=" . $encode_fq_city . "&wt=php&fl=LoginInfoId&rows=100");
```

References:

- https://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters
- https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Common+Query+Parameters

*UPDATE*: If you want to make a permanent change you can configure Solr by editing `solrconfig.xml`, for a rows example see:

- [solrconfig.xml example from cwiki.apache.org](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/RequestHandlers+and+SearchComponents+in+SolrConfig#RequestHandlersandSearchComponentsinSolrConfig-SearchHandlers/)

Comment: it  works!! MR.Kaylined helped me too.
one more question.. do i need to set it explicity with every Solr query or there is any other option to set that with solr config ?